# Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I'm trying to publish an asp.net core v3 app to run under IIS.  I created a virtual directory, converted to application.  It has it's own IIS app pool that is setup with CLR: No Managed Code, 32 bit:False, and Pipeline:Integrated.  Publishing the app to the directory, in creates the default web.config and needed json files as expected.  Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\PatientPlace3.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

If I go to my website's physical directory and manually run "dotnet .\myapp.dll", I can run it at port 5001 no problem.  My client-app and api calls all work fine.  When I try go to the URL under IIS, I get a 503 error, and in the event viewer:

> Unable to locate application dependencies. Ensure that the versions of Microsoft.NetCore.App and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App targeted by the application are installed.

then

> Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
>   Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
>   Possible reasons for this include:
>     * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
>     * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-.\PatientPlace3.dll does not exist.
>     * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

Another clue is that the first time I go to the url, IIS starts up a w3wp process for the DefaultAppPool, not my custom CORE one.  I have aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll in all of the Program FIles\dotnet\shared[frameworkname][version] directories (2.1.8 through 3.0.0), and have the modules installed.  I've tried copying that dll into my app directory, and fully qualifying the dotnet argument.

Always the same error.

Comment: Process Monitor might tell you more about the file access part.

Comment: Thanks Lex.  Tried process monitor, but there is no dotnet.exe under the w3wp.exe process.  I also tried publishing using Deployment Mode: Self-Contained.  That option throws tons of dlls in my site's physical folder, even including aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll.  Still it can't seem to find it.

Comment: Recreating my app pool in IIS somehow seems to have gotten me past this.

Comment: Then you should post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 10):

Recreating my AppPool fixed the problem.  It is identical to the non-working AppPool, so it must be an order of creation issue.  The first AppPool was installed before the v3 version of aspnet core module, or something like that.  Thanks Lex.

Comment: This finally sorted it for me after trying numerous suggestions in addition to changing the processPath from 'dotnet' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet'. The old app pool I was using was set to enable 32-bit applications, disabling this again helped to fix it.

Comment: My application had been assigned to a different app pool, no idea how. But changing it back to the correct app pool fixed the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Silly cause that leads to the same error: specifying an incorrect startup assembly (dll) in the web.config file:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\not_to_be_found.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

This might happen if web.config is not refreshed when publishing and the assembly name has changed.

Comment: Not sure how my coworkers did this, but they did. Always try the quickest potential fixes first, even if they seem unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: In my case this was the problem. I have copied the old web.config and placed in the new project hosting location. Hence there was a dll name change. Thanks Alexei.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error. I looked at the event log errors.
It said

> Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message: It was
> not possible to find any compatible framework version The framework
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found. - The
> following frameworks were found: 2.1.19

so I downloaded and installed version 5 of ASP.NET Core Runtime from

https://versionsof.net/core/5.0/5.0.5/

also did a `iisreset` just to be sure it gets fixed...
and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything. Including running the .EXE instead of dotnet + arguments (having the dll).
IIS keeps on complaining about an invalid web.config.
When switching to 64 bitness it will say:
"Failed to find the RegisterModule entrypoint in the module DLL C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll."

Finally I decided to abandon the IIS idea, and go for a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

My Event Viewer indicated "Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'." also.

I am working on an Asp.Net Core  application (MVC) using .NET5 as target framework. In my case, it was that I did not included the runtimes libraries (I mean, the folders /runtimes/win, runtimes/win-x64, and so on). I also needed to go to my WebSite in the Internet Information Services (IIS) and give permissions to the IIS_USRS user.

Answer (score 0):

There is already one answer mentioning "Recreating the app pool". Since it was running already and I just exchanged some DLLs and got this issue, this could not be the problem. So in my case it was just a simple restarting of the app pool and everything worked fine again.